# DSUM - Data Typed Mismatched in Criteria Expression

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

```
Withdrawal: DSum("[quantity]","Withdrawal","[part_number]= '&[part_number]&'")
```

I am getting the above error due to the statement above.

I have an Orders table, would like to collate and display the withdrawals quantity for each part number. Data type is number, am I missing anything here?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with 2 types of quotes, and doing it improperly. The proper code should be:

```
Withdrawal: DSum("[quantity]","Withdrawal","[part_number]= " & [part_number])
```

In the code above, the second [part_number] was still inside a string so not filling properly. As a result you were comparing part numbers with the string [part_number]

Comment: Thank you so much. The answer works perfectly.... and much appreciated for the explanation. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Missing a quote after the first apostrophe and before the second.

`Withdrawal: DSum("[quantity]","Withdrawal","[part_number]= '" & [part_number] & "'")`

part_number is a text field? If not, remove the apostrophes.

Comment: part_number is number but I am still receiving the same error as mismatched..... still trying and figuring where it went wrong.